# MySQL loop over each value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with 2 columns:
`id`, `tag`

I want to get a result table with `id` and `count_of_tag` but with special counting requirement like this (count distinct tags for each id with id=1 always included):

For each i in id:

```
select id, count(distinct tag) from table where id in (1,i);
```

How can I do this? I only have experience in select statements and new to stored procedure/functions.

----Sample Data-----

```
id |tag
1  |  A
1  |  B
1  |  C
2  |  A
2  |  D
3  |  C
3  |  D
3  |  E
```

----Desired result----

```
id |count
1  |    3
2  |    4
3  |    5
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come up with a solution myself:

```
select 
   id, count(distinct tag)
from
   (select * from table
     union
     select * from
     (select distinct id from table where id<>1) as t1
     CROSS JOIN
     (select distinct tag from table where id=1) as t2) as final
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to include "1" as a tag whether it is present or not.  How about this?

```
select id,
       (count(distinct tag) + (1 - max(tag = 1)))
from table
group by id;
```

The `1 - max(tag = 1)` returns 0 when tag 1 is present and 0 when it is not.

Comment: No. 1 is not a tag, it's an id (a special one). Say when i=3, I want to count distinct tags with id = 1 or 3. Whatever i is, I want to count the distinct tags with id = 1 or i.

Comment: Edited. Could you take a look?

Comment: @user130893 . . . I have no idea what you mean.  I would suggest deleting this question and asking another with sample data and desired results.